# How to position your custom UIView control derived from UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield, position

I have extended `UITextField` so that I can use my custom `myInputView`. But I am having trouble positioning the `myInputView` to a desire location. Doesn't matter what i do to set the CGRect frame of `myInputView` it will position the height be at the bottom of the screen.

See Screenshot:

[image: http://lh3.ggpht.com/_h3ntmj5-XE8/TSK_zj6GfcI/AAAAAAAAAv8/wNWvuXS5Qk8/s640/Screen%20shot%202011-01-03%20at%2010.33.00%20PM.png]

As you can see in the picture the reversed number pad is my custom `inputView`, but I want to be able to position it towards the middle of the screen.

MyTextField.h

```
@interface MyTextField : UITextField {
    UIView *myInputView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myInputView;
@end
```

MyTextField.m

```
@implementation MyTextField
@synthesize myInputView;

- (UIView *)inputView {
    NSLog(@"Return inputView");

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 215);
    [myInputView setFrame:frame]; 

    return myInputView;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [myInputView release];
}
@end
```

Comment: apparently if you assign your custom inputView to a custom UITextField when the TextField becomes first responder it will position at the same height as if it's using the default inputView.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider NOT implementing this in terms of an input view.  Setting the input view lets the system treat it like it treats the keyboard.  You DON'T get to set the frame, only the height.  I would recommend getting rid of the `UITextField`, and replacing it with a `UILabel` with a `UIButton` over it.  Add your custom input view to the main view, and position it offscreen.  When the button is pressed, animate your custom input view back on screen.  When the user makes inputs, just update the label.  Don't worry about first responder or the `UITextField.inputView` at all.